# Matplotlib FuncAnimation in Tkinter - Axes labels not being displayed/retained

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, matplotlib-animation

I am using Python with TKinter as GUI; and Matplotlib's FuncAnimation, to display 2 graphs next to each other. These graphs are representing sensor readings (temperature, humidity), and I would like to label both the x-axis and y-axis. (The matplotlib graph title is not required, but I am including it for testing purposes)

I'll try not to divulge unnecessary details; but in simple terms, I have 2 classes representing the sensors, "temperature" and "humidity", and another class "main_window" to combine both the classes into the Tkinter GUI.

This is a preview of the main.py file; including the main_window class.

```
class main_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_title("Indoor Monitoring System")
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        frame2 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame2.grid(column=1, row=0)

        temperature(frame1, self)
        humidity(frame2, self)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        runObj = main_window()
        runObj.mainloop()
```

and this is a preview of the temperature class

```
class temperature(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)
        plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

        self.x_values = []
        self.y_values = []

        self.counter = 0

        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4), dpi=100)

        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.ax1.set(xlabel="Reading Counter", ylabel="Degrees Celcius")

        label = tk.Label(parent, text="Temperature Graph", font=("Arial", 12)).grid(column=0, row=0)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=parent)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.ani1 = FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval=10000, blit=False)

    def animate(self, i):
        df = pd.read_csv('C:\\log.csv')

        x_temporary_values = df["Counter"]
        y_temp_values = df["Temp"]

        currrow = x_temporary_values[self.counter]

        if currrow is not None:
            self.x_values.append(currrow)
            self.y_values.append(y_temp_values[self.counter])

            self.ax1.plot(self.x_values, self.y_values)
            # self.ax1.set(xlabel="Reading Counter", ylabel="Degrees Celcius")

            self.counter += 1
```

The humidity class is very similar.

I am trying to set the xlabel and ylabel as such:

```
self.ax1.set(xlabel="Reading Counter", ylabel="Degrees Celcius", title="Temperature")
```

I've also tried:

```
self.ax1.set_title("Temperature")
self.ax1.set_xlabel("Reading Counter")
self.ax1.set_ylabel("Degrees Celcius")
```

The title and y_label are initially displayed. After refreshing the graph via the "animate" funxction, the title is retained, the y_label is not. The x_label is never shown.

I have also tried to re-call the self.ax1.set() in the animation function. Does not make a difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: that this setup is the only one that worked for me, in the context of trying to animate the graphs. Most other setups that I was more accustomed to, do not work with FuncAnimation.

Also, note that the UI is not refined by any means (especially font sizes). I am concerned with fixing the label issues first.